# Gumbo file is slimey and too thick.

Tags: gumbo

I used a new type of file powder in gumbo that I have made many times. It came out too thick and slimey. I can thin it down with some chicken stock. How can I fix the slimey texture. It is very unappealing.

Comment: Slimy? That doesn't sound like file. Does your gumbo contain okra? BTW, gumbo file loses character upon cooking. It should be sprinkled on at the end, not cooked in. But I don't think the file is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix the slimey texture.

Okra produces slime because the Okra plant and its fruit contain nasty stuff called mucilage. When you apply heat to the Gumbo, the slime comes out. But there are a few techniques for reducing all that sliminess, namely pan frying or grilling prior to adding it to the Gumbo.

Comment: Welcome Randy - Can you explain why this works?